# Railo 4.2 content type in return header becomes text/xml

Tags: html, xml, coldfusion, railo

My problem here is quite confusing to me, though i fear the answer is something very simple that i am just unable to find

I am using Railo 4.2 at the moment.
we are setting up a decently old webpage for a customer

in many cases we have links like

/filename.cfc?method=dosomething

no matter what is returned, it returns with the content-type : text/xml

I have added 
 but it seems its chosen to be xml before even looking at that.

```
<cffunction name="needhelp" access="remote" output="true" produces="text/html">
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>help!</body></html>
</cffunction>
```

the code above seems simple enough, but it gives an error due to not well formed xml.

just to make things very strange:

```
<cffunction name="needhelp" access="remote" output="true" produces="text/html">
    <cfset SetLocale('no_NO')>
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>help!</body></html>
</cffunction>
```

this code works as i would think it should. It returns as text/html.

I cant understand why this happens, does anyone have any lead i could try to check? :)

Comment: You're probably better off asking Railo questions on their Google group, which gets far more attn than the Railo tag does here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/railo